# ajax php jquery mobile select menu

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

On the same page I have an area to add a patient and a separate patient select menu. If a patient is added, I would like the select menu to show this new patient without refreshing the page.

The select menu is originally populated with:

```
<?php
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `patients` WHERE `company_id` = " .     $user_data['company_id'] . " ORDER BY `patient_firstname`");

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
      echo '<option value="' . $row['patient_id'] . '">' .  $row['patient_firstname'] . ' ' . $row['patient_lastname'] . '</option>';
}
?>
```

When the select menu is used the input fields first_name, last_name, & dob are populated using:

```
$('#patientselect').live('change', function() {
$.ajax({
    url     : 'patientget.php',
    type    : 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    data    : $('#patientform').serialize(),
    success : function( data ) {
                 for(var id in data) {        
                        $(id).val( data[id] );
                 }
              }
});
});
```

which retrieves the information from the patientget.php:

```
$patientId = $_POST['patientselect']; // Selected Patient Id

$result = mysql_query("SELECT `patient_id`, `patient_firstname`,     `patient_lastname`, `patient_dob` FROM `patients` WHERE `patient_id` =     $patientId");
$row    = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);

$patientId      = $row['patient_id'];
$patientFirstName   = $row['patient_firstname'];
$patientLastName    = $row['patient_lastname'];
$patientDob     = $row['patient_dob'];

$arr = array( 
'input#patient_id'      => $patientId, 
'input#patient_firstname'   => $patientFirstName, 
'input#patient_lastname'    => $patientLastName, 
'input#patient_dob'         => $patientDob); 
echo json_encode( $arr );

?>
```

This is my first post, so please let me if I need to provide more/clearer information.

Thank in advance!! Adam

Comment: Yes we need a QUESTION...?What is it that you're asking...?

Comment: mysql is deprecated use mysqli or PDO instead.

Comment: @ gdoron. When a user adds a new patient, I would like the select list to refresh with the new user as an option without refreshing the page.